# IvyDB: St as the only unknown variable in the BS formula

Tags: options, black-scholes

Good afternoon.

I have a dataset of options (IvyDB), with the price of the options, and all the information needed to retreive the price from the Black-Scholes formula.

All except the price of the underlying St. I just can't see how to get this info from the BS formula, as the call price,, d1 and d2 all depends on St.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2):

There is another formula called the Black 1976 formula that is equivalent to the Black Scholes formula but uses the "forward price" $F_t$ instead of the spot price $S_t$.

If you have prices for both Puts and Calls for a given maturity you can estimate $F$ as follows.

1. Examine all strikes $K_i$ and select the one where the price difference between calls and puts is as small as possible. Call this strike K.
2. Compute the forward as $F=K+e^{rT}(call - put)$

Once you have the forward you can use it, together with the Black formula to find the implied volatilities (which is what I assume you are after) at each strike level.

HTH

Comment: Another way to do it is to plot the points $(K_i,C_i-P_i)$ for all strikes with the same maturity date. By fitting a line to these points (i.e. by linear regression) you can find both $F$ and $e^{rT}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that from IvDB you can get the prices of the underlying securities. If you are using IvDB I am assuming that you are using OptionMetrics.

If that is the case and if you also have access to WRDS/CRSP then you can download the quotes from CRSP. You will need to link CRSP and OptionMetrics data using Cusips.